# Using TinyMCE with Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, tinymce, textarea

I'm currently trying to use tinymce with Ionic and have come across a strange problem. Displayed below is my index.html page. If I utilise it in this way then it works perfectly and I am given a tinymce textarea box to work with.

However, if I try to call it in any of my other html files then it doesn't change the look/functionality of the `<textarea>` tag.

Is there a way I should be calling it from within my other files?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea'
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <textarea>Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</textarea>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does "other html" files mean here? can you show the code there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic uses angularjs, by "calling" i assume you mean initializing the plugin in the head of your script file.  This will work on your index page when it loads.   I suspect that the reason it doesn't work in your "other html" files is because the html is rendered on the page before the plugin is initialized (if it really is).

The simple solution is creating a custom directive for this plugin.  If for some reason you are unable to do that then you can check [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) package out on github.  Haven't used it before myself though.

If you are concerned about having the plugin load even on pages where it isn't really needed then you can just use [LazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).

Comment: This worked. I injected it via the controller for that page. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post you actual solution? I.E where in the code you placed it.